# Is there any software for visual display of disk space?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an application which allows me to see what is consuming the most disk space and also *to delete the files* from there.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen the question because it has a different starting point and scope than the linked question. I know there will be a significant chunk of overlap in the suggested tools and answers but that's not enough imho; e. g. the author of the linked question already knows Baobab but failed to run it as super-user.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

My personal favorite is [GNOME Disk Usage Analyzer (baobab)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DiskUsageAnalyzer):

[image: baobab screenshot]

You can install it with

```
sudo apt install baobab
```

Select any file from the table on the left side to move it to trash on right click.

[image]

Comment: It seems installed in Gnome. How do you get that gradient look? And can't you delete files graphically with it?

Comment: @empedokles no, you can't delete files and I don't know about the gradient. That's just a screenshot I found online.

Comment: This come pre-installed, search `disk` in the dash, in Ubuntu and you can delete files by right clicking them and choosing `move to rubbish bin`

Comment: @empedokles I stand corrected, it seems like you can delete files. I've never used it that way though.

Comment: Seems to work on the left, but not on the graphical side. Disks brings up something else (a partition manager).

Comment: `Disk` is just a search term `disk usage analyzer` is one of the results. @empedokles

Comment: I see, it's called different in German and something else jumped up. It's a pitty that Ubuntu uses German translations, it makes things more complicated IMO.

Comment: The first choice for GNOME users =)

Answer (score 8):

There is a fully rewritten version of KDirStat, by the same author, named [QDirStat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat). Fast, customizable, using Qt5, desktop-agnostic (not depending on KDE components), and showing a squared view rather than concentric circles, which I personally find clearer. 
There is a [ppa available](https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ubuntu/qdirstat) for the installation.

[image: qdirstat snapshot]

Answer (score 6):

Personally I like [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/)

[image: img]

you can install with

`sudo apt-get install kdirstat`

Answer (score 6):

If you're using KDE, I'd recommend [`filelight`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filelight)

[image: filelight screenshot from debian.net]

You may install it using:

```
apt-get install filelight
```

It is very similar to GNOME baobab recommended by terdon.

The wikipedia entry says:

> Filelight is a KDE graphical disk usage analyzer, part of the KDE
>   Utils package, which uses the sunburst chart technique to display disk
>   usage. Instead of showing a tree view of the files within a partition
>   or directory, or even a columns-represent-directories view like
>   xdiskusage, it shows a series of concentric pie charts representing
>   the various directories within the requested partition or directory
>   and the amount of space they use[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filelight) (this method being known as a
>   sunburst chart, ring chart, or multilevel pie chart).
>
> A user may also click on the pie chart segment representing
>   a particular directory, and repeat the analysis
>   for that directory,[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjFph.png) right click that
>   segment to open a file manager or terminal emulator in that location,
>   or copy to clipboard or delete the directory, and they may right click
>   the segment representing a file to open it, copy it to the clipboard,
>   or delete it.

Answer (score 6):

If you happen to be on the command line, you can use:
**[ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu)**
Ncdu is a disk usage analyzer with an ncurses interface. It is designed to find space hogs on a remote server where you don't have an entire graphical setup available, but it is a useful tool even on regular desktop systems. Ncdu aims to be fast, simple and easy to use, and should be able to run in any minimal POSIX-like environment with ncurses installed.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/jdiskreport/) is a nice tool, it requires Java 6 or later, Java 7 is recommended.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MATE Disk Usage Analyzer (`mate-disk-usage-analyzer`) may be used too. It is installable as part of MATE utilities package

```
sudo apt-get install mate-utils
```

and looks like GNOME Disk Usage Analyzer - see screenshot below

[image: <code>mate-disk-usage-analyzer</code> on Ubuntu MATE 16.04.6 LTS]